# Setup PERMANENT TAP adapter in VPS without dissapear after reboot

Tags: configuration, tap, adapter

I'm installing Softether in a new VPS and all works fine. System is a CentOS 6.5 32bit.

The issue is that after rebooting the VPS the TAP adapter dissapear.

I would like to know if I can define permanently a TAP NIC adapter with a fixed configuration after every reboot.

Any tip ? thanks

Comment: Have you created a startup script like described at https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/7._Installing_SoftEther_VPN_Server/7.3_Install_on_Linux_and_Initial_Configurations#7.3.8_Registering_a_Startup_Script ?

Comment: I created a similar one I saw in a blog, but I saw some errors .... will work on it, the problem is that I'm not expert in this area .....